# what is the meaning of static import in ES6?

Tags: javascript

> One major advantage in ESM over CJS is how ESM has — and
>   encourages — a way of statically importing dependencies. Static
>   imports vastly improve the introspection capabilities of module
>   systems, given they can be analyzed statically and lexically extracted
>   from the abstract syntax tree (AST) of each module in the system

— [Mastering Modular JavaScript by *Nicolas Bevacqua*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ndpqDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT26&lpg=PT26&dq=One+major+advantage+in+ESM+over+CJS+is+how+ESM+has+%E2%80%94+and+encourages+%E2%80%94+a+way+of+statically+importing+dependencies.+Static+imports+vastly+improve+the+introspection+capabilities+of+module+systems,+given+they+can+be+analyzed+statically+and+lexically+extracted+from+the+abstract+syntax+tree+(AST)+of+each+module+in+the+system&source=bl&ots=sPRndr6S_B&sig=HtMfKAHC0w4qUfflWEwmLLWOs2E&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjuq7LE557eAhXsKMAKHcx2BrUQ6AEwA3oECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=One%20major%20advantage%20in%20ESM%20over%20CJS%20is%20how%20ESM%20has%20%E2%80%94%20and%20encourages%20%E2%80%94%20a%20way%20of%20statically%20importing%20dependencies.%20Static%20imports%20vastly%20improve%20the%20introspection%20capabilities%20of%20module%20systems%2C%20given%20they%20can%20be%20analyzed%20statically%20and%20lexically%20extracted%20from%20the%20abstract%20syntax%20tree%20(AST)%20of%20each%20module%20in%20the%20system&f=false)

i do not understand this ,anyone can help?

Comment: Well let's see how we can help. What parts don't you understand?

Comment: What part of it do you not understand? Do you know what "analysis" means here?

Comment: a way of statically importing dependencies,how to explain

Answer (score 14):

JavaScript's native module system, sometimes called ESM (**E**CMA**S**cript **M**odules), has both static and dynamic import. It started with just static import (which is still dominant), and then dynamic import was added by the [dynamic import proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import), which is now complete and well-supported in browsers, Node.js, and bundlers (though some bundlers add restrictions if you want them to do tree-shaking).

What do we mean by "static"? When you use an `import` declaration, it must be at the top level of the module, outside of any control-flow statements, and it must use a string *literal* to say what module to import from, not just a string. That's so the relationship between modules can be determined by *static analysis* (by just *parsing* the code, without *running* it). This is valid:

```
import foo from "./mod.js";
```

That's a *static import*.

This is not valid:

```
// Invalid (but keep reading for an alternative)
if (someCondition) {
    import foo from "./mod1.js";
} else {
    import foo from "./mod2.js";
}
```

Nor this:

```
// Invalid (but keep reading for an alternative)
import foo from someCondition ? "./mod1.js" : "./mod2.js";
```

If that worked, it would be a *dynamic import*; what you're importing varies depending on a condition determined at runtime. (JavaScript does have dynamic import now, just not with that syntax, more below.)

And similarly, exports are declared with static `export` declarations, not runtime code.

CommonJS (CJS, a variant of which is used by Node.js) has only dynamic import and export, via the `require` function and assignment to the `exports` object:

```
// Valid CommonJS
let foo;
if (someCondition) {
    foo = require("./mod1.js");
} else {
    foo = require("./mod2.js");
}

// or more simply:

const foo = require(someCondition ? "./mod1.js" : "./mod2.js");
```

Because there are situations where determining your import at runtime is useful, JavaScript also has dynamic import now via something that looks like a function call (but isn't):

```
// Valid ESM (now that dynamic import is done)
import(someCondition ? "./mod1.js" : "./mod2.js")
.then(({default: foo}) => {
    // ...code here using `foo` from either `mod1` or `mod2`...
});
```

The `import()` pseudo-function returns a promise which is either fulfilled with the module namespace object for the module (which has the module's exports as properties), or is rejected with an error.

The dynamic `import()` pseudo-function combines particularly well with [top-level `await`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await). Top-level `await` likes you write the above like this:

```
// Valid ESM (now that dynamic import and top-level `await` are done)
const foo = await import(someCondition ? "./mod1.js" : "./mod2.js").default;
// ...code here using `foo` from either `mod1` or `mod2`...
```

Exports are still statically defined, though you could always export an object with runtime-defined properties.

---

Looking at the examples of dynamic import, you may be thinking: "Hey, he's left off rejection handlers! If there's a problem loading the module, he'll get an "unhandled rejection" error in the console!" Yup, I will. It'll be next to the module loading error that's already there, and possibly the network error that caused the module load to fail. Which is what you would get if a static module load failed, too (just without the unhandled rejection error). Module load failure is a fairly catastrophic thing. :-) But **if** you have something optional, you could certainly handle rejection:

```
let localization;
try {
    // Try to get localization information for the user's language...
    localization = import(`./locale-${navigator.language}.js`);
} catch {
    // ...that failed, fall back to default
    localization = import(`./locale-default.js`);
}
```

*(The sharp-eyed will note that the above uses [optional `catch` binding](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-catch-binding) syntax.)*

Comment: *(Er, um...if you find the above helpful, you can read more about JavaScript's module loading [in my book](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder?tab=profile).)*