# Is there any way of executing ES syntax in a Node.js shell?

Tags: node.js, shell

Let's say I create a file called `file.mjs` with the following content:

```
import axios from 'axios' 

const response = await axios.get('https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse.php?lat=-23.513442&lon=-46.384794&zoom=18&format=jsonv2')
console.log(response.data)
```

Let's also say I execute this file with the command `node file.mjs`... Because of its `mjs` extension, I'm capable of executing this file as a module and so I can use `await` outside the `async` function. Also, I can use the `import` statement to declare my libraries.

So far everything works fine... But let's say I open a Node.js shell by executing the command `node`. I'll end up in a prompt like:

```
 user@computer  ~  node
Welcome to Node.js v16.14.2.
Type ".help" for more information.
>
```

This prompt will not accept ES syntax inside it... That means I'll have to import libraries with the `require` function and I'll have to use `async` functions in order to use `await`. Is there any way of making a Node.js shell execute ES syntax? Just so I can execute the javascript from my sample exactly as it is?

Comment: ES6 static imports are static, so the info about the path etc. must be available when the script starts (without e.g. 'if', executing functions first, etc), so I think it won't be compatible with the nature of REPL. 
`If that worked, it would be a dynamic import; what you're importing varies depending on a condition determined at runtime.` (I copied that last sentence from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52965907/what-is-the-meaning-of-static-import-in-es6  )
The REPL can process dynamic imports, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic import, which is the `import()` function, in the REPL.
Let's say you're in a folder that has a `node_modules` folder with `axios` installed. Then, you can simply open the REPL in there and do something like this:

```
const axios = (await import("axios")).default;
```

This is the only way to use `import` in a REPL, you cannot load your `file.mjs` exactly like that and would have to use dynamic import in your `file.mjs` instead.